# $ \lim_\limits{n \to \infty}{\frac{10^n+n^2}{n!}} $

Tags: limits

$$ \lim_\limits{n \to \infty}{\frac{10^n+n^2}{n!}} $$

Any hints on how to take on this limit? I do not know how to deal with the factorial in the denominator.

Comment: It there a typo. I don't see any factorial. Moreover is $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Oops, typed in the wrong limit. Editing.

Comment: There are a host of tests (e.g., ratio test, root test, etc.) that can be used to find limits of these types.  Which ones do you know?

Comment: Right now I know of the squeeze theorem. I am about to learn the root and ratio tests.

Comment: $n!$ grows faster than any exponential function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Split the fraction up: ${10^n +n^2 \over n!}={10^n \over n!} + {n^2 \over n!}$

Note that:

${n^2 \over n!}={n \over n-1}{1 \over (n-2)!}$

Now $\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over (n-2)!}=0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}{n \over n-1}=1$, hence $\lim_{n \to \infty}{n^2 \over n!}=0$

Also, ${10^n \over n!}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}{10 \over i}=\left (\prod_{i=1}^{10}{10 \over i} \right ) \left (\prod_{i=11}^{n-1}{10 \over i} \right){10 \over n}≤\left (\prod_{i=1}^{10}{10 \over i} \right ){10 \over n}$ for $n≥11$.

Since $\left (\prod_{i=1}^{10}{10 \over i} \right )$ is a constant and ${10 \over n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we get $\lim_{n \to \infty}{10^n \over n!}=0$

Therefore: $\lim_{n \to \infty}{10^n +n^2 \over n!}=0+0=0$